# Gitzilla: Integration of github-project in Bugzilla

Tags: github, installation, bugzilla, pybugz, gitzilla

I am working on a Debian server, where I installed bugzilla. According to the suggestions in the gitzilla-installation guidelines, I would like to integrate Gitzilla to a project on github.com, using the github.com-project as my central repo. Therefore, I am not quite sure, where to do the following steps:

```
Switch to the hooks directory (/path/to/repository/.git/hooks) and delete the post-receive and update hooks.

Link (or copy) the gitzilla provided hooks:

ln -s $(which gitzilla-post-receive) post-receive
ln -s $(which gitzilla-update) update
```

Moreover, I tested to choose my github.com-URL to integrate in the /etc/gitzillarc, but without success. PyBugz is installed, and I defined the link to bugzilla, the user_name and PW of the bugzilla-admin.

Best,

H.M.

Comment: It would be great, if someone could help me with this issue...

Answer (score 0):

`https://github.com/your_repository.git/.git/hooks` will be the path where you should execute the steps.

In case you have a bare repository, then `https://github.com/your_repository.git/hooks` would be the path.